# How to convert array elements and strings into subsequent separate objects in array using JOLT?

Tags: json, jolt

I'm trying to transform a record using JOLT. String elements - from `access_level` field and Array elements (from `tag` field) have to be transformed to separate objects in `properties` array. But instead 2 elements are merged into one:
Here is the input:

```
{
  "access_level": "public",
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 174,
      "tag_name": "machine-learning",
      "tag_path": "machine-learning"
    },
    {
      "id": 393,
      "tag_name": "chinese",
      "tag_path": "chinese"
    }
  ]
}
```

and spec file:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "access_level": {
        "*": {
          "@1": "properties[#1].value",
          "#terms-of-use": "properties[#1].type.code"
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "*": {
          "tag_name": "properties[#2].value",
          "#keyword": "properties[#2].type.code"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

expected output is:

```
{
"properties" : [ 
    {
      "value" :  "public",
      "type" : {
        "code" : "terms-of-use"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "type" : {
        "code" : "keyword"
      },
      "value" : "machine-learning"
    },
    {
      "type" : {
        "code" : "keyword"
      },
      "value" : "chinese"
    } ]
  }
```

but `access_level` and first value from `tags` are getting merged:

```
{
  "properties" : [ {
    "value" : [ "public", "machine-learning" ],
    "type" : {
      "code" : "keyword"
    }
  }, {
    "type" : {
      "code" : [ "terms-of-use", "keyword" ]
    },
    "value" : "chinese"
  } ]
}
```

if there is no `access_level` on input the output looks fine - 2 objects are created in `properties` array

Answer (score 0):

You can apply consecutive **shift** transformations using ampersand notations to determine the *keys* while producing one array(`p`), which's derived from `tags`, and an element, which's derived from `access_level`, in the first step; then  rename that array to `properties` while adding that element to it in the last step in such a way :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "tags": {
        "*": {
          "tag_name": "p.[&1].value",
          "#keyword": "p.[&1].type.code"
        }
      },
      "access_level": {
        "*": {
          "@(3,access_level)": "&1.value",
          "#terms-of-use": "&1.type.code"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "properties"
    }
  }
]
```